how to use multiple implicit $and operators with multiple $in operators in Mongo
I want to check with $regex search whether 3 words in particular field and if present return all documents inside collection.
{

  $and: [

    { "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "journal", $options: "i" } },

    { "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "physics", $options: "i" } },

    { "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "Nuclear", $options: "i" } }

  ]

}

in case match not found do the same $regex search for the same words in another field and return all documents from the  collection.
{

  $and: [

    { "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "journal", $options: "i" } },

    { "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "physics", $options: "i" } },

    { "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "Nuclear", $options: "i" } }

  ]

}

when Tried with multiple $and operators I can getting expected answer .
when tried to combine $and operators using single $or operators with multiple implicit $and oeprators not able to perform the query.
{
 
    { $or: [
        { "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "journal", $options: "i" } },
        { "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "physics", $options: "i" } },
        { "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "Nuclear", $options: "i" } }
      ]
    },
    { "abbreviatedTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "Nuclear", $options: "i"}},
    { "abbreviatedTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "phy", $options: "i" } },
    { "abbreviatedTitle.hasValue.value": { $regex: "Nuclear", $options: "i" } }
  
}

Can Anyone help in this?
My document structure will be :
{
  "_id": "Entity1",
  "createdDate": "sssss",
  "modifiedDate": "aaaaa",
  "sourceType": {
    "hasValue": {
      "value": "journ"
    },
    "origin": "zzzzzzz",
    "score": 6.5
  },
  "description": [],
  "preferredTitle": [
    {
      "hasValue": {
        "language": "und",
        "value": "Journal of Physics G: Nuclear and Particle Physics"
      },
      "origin": "ssddeedddd",
      "score": 6.5
    }
  ],
  "alternateTitle": [
    {
      "hasValue": {
        "language": "und",
        "value": "Journal of physics. G, Nuclear and particle physics : an Institute of Physics journal"
      },
      "origin": "sdsdsdsdsd",
      "score": 6.5
    }
  ],
  "abbreviatedTitle": [
    {
      "hasValue": {
        "language": "eng",
        "value": "journal.of.nuclear.phy."
      }
    }
  ],
  "translatedTitle": [],
  "transliteratedTitle": [],
  "identifier": [
    {
      "hasValue": {
        "value": "000000",
        "type": "pISSN"
      },
      "origin": "dfedcfgddeds",
      "score": 6.5
    },
    {
      "hasValue": {
        "value": "111111",
        "type": "eISSN"
      },
      "origin": "sssddsrefdfdf",
      "score": 6.5
    },
    {
      "hasValue": {
        "value": "22222",
        "type": "aaaaaaa"
      },
      "origin": "cdeefff",
      "score": 6.5
    },

  ],
  "alternateIdentifier": [],
  "homePage": {
    "hasValue": {
      "value": "http://fggfgfgfgfgfgf"
    },
    "origin": "csdsesdsdsd",
    "score": 6.5
  },
  "hasSubject": [
    {
      "type": "edm:Concept",
      "identifier": {
        "type": "idtype:ASJC",
        "value": "333333"
      },
      "origin": "fdfrefefef",
      "score": 6.5
    }
  ],
  "hasSourceQualityTag": [],
  "hasLicenseModel": [],
  "productDecision": [],
  "_class": "dsss"
}


@YongShun edited the question with document structure pls

Your query is not valid as it is not a valid object. Wrap the condition into the logical operator (depending on your search criteria), which should resolve.
With outer $or - Match documents that fulfill either the first condition or the remaining 3 conditions.
With outer $and - Match documents that fulfill the first and remaining 3 conditions.
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": {
            $regex: "journal",
            $options: "i"
          }
        },
        {
          "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": {
            $regex: "physics",
            $options: "i"
          }
        },
        {
          "preferredTitle.hasValue.value": {
            $regex: "Nuclear",
            $options: "i"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "abbreviatedTitle.hasValue.value": {
        $regex: "Nuclear",
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "abbreviatedTitle.hasValue.value": {
        $regex: "phy",
        $options: "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "abbreviatedTitle.hasValue.value": {
        $regex: "Nuclear",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  ]
})

Demo @ Mongo Playground
